# C/C++ Event driven monitoring the termination of a non-child program

Tags: c++, c, sockets, signals, pipe

**Problem:**

I need to know when a process terminates - knowing only it's PID. However, I also have the ability to modify the source of all processes involved, so theoretically I can do whatever I need. All "efficient" ideas are welcome.

**Strategy 1:**

I have researched `select()`, `pselect()`, `poll()`, `ppoll()`, `epoll()`. My understanding is that I will have to connect a socket for each process I want to monitor, in order to obtain a file descriptor. Then I would need to use a zero timeout value to actually poll the running processes to see if the socket was available for reading in order to know if it was alive or dead.

**Strategy 2:**

If I create multiple pipes between a monitoring daemon and other processes, can I write to a pipe, but never read on the other end and wait for and handle a `SIGPIPE` signal?

**Conclusion:**

At this point, I am in favor of strategy 2, but I would like to ask the community for advice or pitfalls associated with this approach. Is my understanding of strategy 1 correct, with the assumption that I only want to know about the termination of a process and nothing else? Also, is my approach for strategy 2 too naive and will it consume system resources I am unaware of?

Comment: Strategy 1 need only one socket to handle all the processes since the function you mentioned will do the multiplexing.

Comment: Are those child processes of the daemon or "unrelated" processes?

Comment: Non-child - unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your monitor create a Unix domain socket to which each of the monitored processes can connect. If you pass those socket descriptors to `poll` with no events set in the `pollfd` structures, you will receive `POLLHUP` events when one of the monitored processes exits and its socket is closed.